# Prove that $S_{X \text{, fin}}$ is a normal subgroup of $S_X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For any set $X$ and a bijection $f:X \rightarrow X$, we define the support of $f$, denoted $$\text{supp}(f)=\{x \in X:f(x) \neq x\}$$
Let $S_X=\{f:X \rightarrow X : f \text{ is  a bijection}\}$ be the symmetric group of $X$.

For an infinite set $X$, we let $S_{X \text{, fin}}=\{f \in S_X: |\text{supp(f)}| < \infty\}$

**Question:-** Prove that $S_{X \text{, fin}}$ is a normal subgroup of $S_X$

**My Approach:-** I think this is wrong as for $f(x) \in S_X$ and $s(x) \in S_{X \text{, fin}}$.

If we define $f(x)=x+1$ and $s(x)=x$ when $x \geq 3$ and $s(1)=2$ and $s(2)=1$, then very clearly $f(s(1))=3$ and $s(f(1))=1$ showing $S_{X \text{, fin}}$ is not a normal subgroup of $S_X$

Where am I wrong. Can anyone give me a hint on this problem.

Comment: Is it obvious it is a subgroup, first? To prove it is normal, this is really a case of just working out the definition and figuring out what the support of $\sigma\phi\sigma^{-1}$ is when $\phi\in S_{X,fin}$ and $\sigma\in S_X$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was able to prove that it is a subgroup. But I am not able to use the definition of normal subgroup, as I keep getting stuck after writing what you have written. Moreover, I think I have found a counterexample to this. Could you please check it?

Comment: You have not stated the set $X$ on which your functions $f$ and $s$ are defined.

Comment: Being normal does not mean $fs=sf$ but rather that $fsf^{-1}\in S_{X,fin}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher $X=\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This means the |support of $fsf^{-1}|< \infty$. How do I prove this? And $fsf^{-1}$ is a bijection, from $X \rightarrow X$. So, $fsf^{-1} \in S_{X \text{, fin}}$. This seems correct

Comment: All you've shown in your "counter-example" is that $fs\neq sf$, which is not enough to prove it is not a normal subgroup. And no, the union of countable finite sets is not finite.

Comment: Hint: show that the support of $fsf^{-1}$ is exactly $\{f(x)\colon x\in\mathop{\rm supp}(s)\}$.

Comment: @GregMartin Since $f$ is a bijection, we have $|\text{supp}(fsf^{-1})| = |\text{supp}(s)|$ ie $|\text{supp}(fsf^{-1})|< \infty$. Is this the complete proof?

Answer (score 0):

One must not forget that the construction $fsf^{-1}$ only consists in relabeling the elements of $s$ by the concerned elements of $f$, so if $s$ moves a finite number of points then so does $fsf^{-1}$, namely those points that have been relabeled. There is another argument: if $s$ only moves a finite number of points then it has a cycke structure of a finite number of finite cycles, since conjugaction preserves cycle structure $fsf^{-1}$ also moves but a finite number of points.